# Which jQuery library do I need to import to show both Dialogue box and chart

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a JSP page where I have some scripts for chart and jQuery dialogue box.

Here is my supporting files..

```
<link type="text/css" href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<%--<script src="JqueryPlugins/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JqueryPlugins/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JqueryPlugins/exporting.js"></script>
```

Now my problem is that if I comment the supporting file ...

```
 <%--<script src="JqueryPlugins/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
```

Then dialogue box will be shown and when i comment this file..

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then chart is showing.I dont know where the problem is ..

Is is version mismatch problem..
Please help me.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two jQuery instances 1.4.1 and 1.5.2, if you include both that might not working correctly. You need only one of them. I'll take 1.5.2. There are any specific reason you are using 1.5.2? There are more recent version of jQuery. check jQuery website for see the most recent one!